# Shell script: fetching files from single server using multiple users(50+). SFTP protocol password less

Tags: linux, shell, unix, rsa, sftp

I m using a shell script to pull files from server using multiple users(50+users). I want it should use sftp communication. As we are using sftp do i have to configure the each users .ssh directory in server with my public key?. what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use 'expect'.

Comment: More a [su] question. How are you getting access to the users's home directories? Do you have the password for each, or do you have root access or what?

Comment: We have the all username and password.